# Function Secret Sharing

Tags: secret-sharing

Bob has constructed a non-linear function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ of moderate complexity (i.e., evaluation takes on the order of seconds on a modern computer). Is it possible to share a function $g: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ of the same asymptotic complexity with Alice, such that:

(1) $g$ reveals nothing about $f$.

(2) $y':=g(x)$ reveals nothing about $y:=f(x)$.

(3) $f(x) = h(g(x),k(x))$ for functions $k,h$ that can be efficiently constructed and evaluated (i.e., at least an order of magnitude faster than $f,g$).

If that's not possible:

- what if we allow other (co-)domains for $f,g$?
- what if we relax conditions 1 & 2 to "reveals as little as possible"?
- what if we assume that $g$ is a black box (i.e., its computations cannot be accessed and condition 1 trivially holds)?

In the context of a specific application: is it possible to let an untrusted party execute a secret algorithm, such that the computational burden is on the untrusted party and the output is meaningless unless combined with an easily computable secret key.

Comment: In cryptography, we seldom use $\mathbb R$ as function source or destination, because there is no general way to represent a real as a finite expression. Even a simple $f$ (like identity or $x\mapsto x^2$) takes unbounded time to evaluate. Instead of reals, we typically use bitstrings of size determined by a security parameters. It's perhaps OK (but still unusual) to use the floating point approximations of a reals.